# How to utilize CommonJS on Rails App requiring a JS Module Asset inside a Gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, commonjs

I have a Rails 4.1 Application, `MyApp`, that is using a Gem called `shared-assets`. This Gem was initialized using `bundle gem foo` to create a very barebones Ruby Gem that will contain assets (Stylesheets, JavaScript, and Views) that any Rails app can reuse.

`MyApp` is also using **CommonJS** for JavaScript to better encapsulate code and define dependencies. `MyApp` has a mediator file (`assets/javascripts/mediator/registration-page.module.js.coffee`) which is trying to require a JavaScript module that exists within the `shared-assets` Gem. The module JS file was added to the `application.js` pipeline but on page load throws a JavaScript error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: module is not defined`.

Inspecting the source JavaScript files on the page I can see that the mediator living within `MyApp` is setup properly:

`MyApp -->` **mediator/registration-page.module.js.coffee**

```
this.require.define({"mediator/registration-page":function(exports, require, module){(function() {
  var Checkbox, initialize, test;

  // Module that exists within the `shared-assets` Gem
  Checkbox = require('./shared-assets/modules/checkbox');

  test = function() {
    return 'success';
  };

  initialize = function() {
    return console.log('registration init');
  };

  module.exports = {
    init: initialize,
    test: test
  };

}).call(this);
;}});
```

The Checkbox module that exists within the `shared-assets` Gem however, does not get setup like the JS file in `MyApp`. Instead, it is just compiled as a classic `Coffee` to `JS`.

`shared-assets -->` **modules/checkbox.module.js.coffee**

```
(function() {
  var Selector, checkboxButtonClicked, checkboxToggle;

  Selector = {
    checkboxContainer: '.check-option'
  };

  checkboxButtonClicked = function(e) {
    console.log('Checkbox has been clicked');
    return false;
  };

  module.exports = {
    clicked: checkboxButtonClicked
  };

}).call(this);
```

So `module` is not defined here because I am assuming it is not setup in the normal **CommonJS** format as `registration-page.module.js.coffee` was compiled as.

I am requiring **CommonJS** in `MyApp` Gemfile and the `application.js`.  I also added a `runtime_dependency` for **CommonJS** in the `shared-assets` Gemspec.

**MyApp Gemfile**

```
...
gem 'sprockets-commonjs', '~> 0.0.6'
...
```

**shared-assets Gemspec**

```
Gem::Specification.new do |spec|
  ...
  spec.add_runtime_dependency "sprockets-commonjs", "~> 0.0.6"
  ...
end
```

**MyApp application.js**

```
//= require jquery
//= require sprockets/commonjs.js

//= require shared-assets/modules/checkbox.module
//= require mediator/registration-page.module
```

Is this even possible to setup? Using a Gem as a "shared resource" for JavaScript modules that can be used with CommonJS? If so, what am I doing wrong here? Does the Gem need to be setup as a Rails Gem instead of a barebones Gem?

Any feedback or help is appreciated here folks!

So while trying to investigate why this isn't working, I enclosed the `checkbox.module.js.coffee` located in the `shared-assets` Gem inside the CommonJS wrapper. Doing this fixed the JS error, but led to more confusion as the exported methods were not available in the module. I was able to require it without an issue but nothing was exported.